# How can I use variable as resource's path?

Tags: java, android

this function siply calls a method passing the id from an object:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     showDesc("cgpc_1c");
}
```

The method has to get the value of a string in strings.xml and pass it to an activity:

```
private void showDesc(String id){

    String path = "R.string." + id; 
    String id_desc = getResources().getString(path);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(Cgpc.this, Description.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("ID_DESC", id_desc);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

But... this didn't like to Java, telling that instead of a string as path, I need an integer... how can I solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: why bundle? just intent.putExtra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using getIdentifier:

1 - add this method

```
protected final static int getResourceID
(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
{
    final int ResourceID =
        ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (ResourceID == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
        (
            "No resource string found with name " + resName
        );
    }
    else
    {
        return ResourceID;
    }
}
```

2 - call it so:

```
getResourceID("myStringName", "string", getApplicationContext());
```